# initialize an IEnumerable property using reflection in c# (propertyInfo)

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

Assuming a class (could be others)

```
class Foo()
{
     IEnumerable<int> SomeNumbers { get; set; }
     IEnumerable<string> SomeStrings { get; set; }       
     int[] ArrayOfInt { get; set; }
     List<int> AListOfIntegers { get; set; }
}
```

And a method

```
void Initialize(object obj)
{
     var props = obj.getType().GetProperties();
     foreach(var prop in props)
     {
         //Some logic in case property is a single value, this is using:
         //Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType, null)

         var list = //Do Some Magic
         prop.SetValue(obj, list, null);
     }
}
```

How to create a list of the right type?

I tried:

```
var list = property.PropertyType.GetConstructor(new CType[0]).Invoke(new object[0]);
```

But this don't work since IEnumerable does n't have constructors (it is an interface), but any supertype would be fine here.

```
var list = Enumerable.Empty<property.PropertyType.MemberType>();
```

Isn't even legal

Comment: You can call `Enumerable.Empty` with reflection, but you realize that there are an awful lot of other types that don't expose public parameterless constructors, right? This isn't going to work as a general approach - it will only work if you've got a very restricted set of types to deal with.

Comment: Having a parameterless constructor (for a know supertype) would be an acceptable precondition.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "for a known supertype" here. For a start, you mean implementation here (for an interface) - but what are you going to do for abstract classes? Are you planning on having some sort of list of "For this abstract class or interface, use *this* concrete type" etc?

Comment: Yes, It would be possible to have an attribute annotation (like the XmlSerializer uses) on the property.

Comment: Okay, so now the question is really "How can I decorate a property with an attribute, retrieve that at execution time and use that to determine which class to instantiate". That's a fairly different question.

Comment: Well, it would probably turn out in that. But I had that use case planned for a later iteration. While the accepted answer does solve my problem for now. I do realize (thanks to your questions) I'll probably have to rewrite it later on when I will add addition test. But this is inherent in TTD, is n't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create instance of `List<T>` that inherints `IEnumerable<T>` with this code:

```
var genericType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();     
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType));
```

Resulted `instance` could be set as property value.

```
prop.SetValue(obj, instance, null);
```

Also you can create empty `Enumerable<T>` using this code:

```
var genericType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();             
var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Empty").MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
var emptyEnumerable = method.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: You are changing your solutions faster then I can try them out... But assuming you are improving your answer, go on :)

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen sorry for lots of changes. I usually late with the answer so I've hastened this time and made a lot of typos :) Current version should work :)